# C++: Confusion with forward declaring classes and using `#include` statements

Tags: c++

Here's my `main.cpp`:

```
...
#include "primitive.h"
#include "intersection.h"
...
```

And my `Primitive.h`:

```
#ifndef PRIMITIVE_H_
#define PRIMITIVE_H_

#include "intersection.h"

// Forward declaration
class Intersection;

class Primitive {
    public:
        bool intersect(Ray& ray, float* tHit, Intersection* in) {
            return false;
        }
};

class GeometricPrimitive : public Primitive {
    public:
        bool intersect(Ray& ray, float* tHit, Intersection* in) {
            DifferentialGeometry differentialGeometry;
            if (!shape->intersect(ray, tHit, &differentialGeometry)) {
                return false;
            }
            in->primitive = this;
            in->differentialGeometry = differentialGeometry;
            return true;
        }

        bool intersectP(Ray& ray) {
            return shape->intersectP(ray);
        }

        BRDFCoefficients getBRDF(DifferentialGeometry& differentialGeometry, BRDFCoefficients* brdf) {
            return material->getBRDF(differentialGeometry, brdf);
        }
};

#endif
```

And my `Intersection.h`:

```
#ifndef INTERSECTION_H_
#define INTERSECTION_H_

// Forward declaration
class Primitive;

class Intersection {
    public:
        Primitive *primitive;

        Intersection() {

        }

        Intersection(DifferentialGeometry differntialGeometry, Primitive *primitive) {
            this->differentialGeometry = differentialGeometry;
            this->primitive = primitive;
        }
};
#endif
```

When I leave out the line `#include "intersection.h"` in `Primitive.h`, I get the error `error: member access into incomplete type 'Intersection'` in lines

`in->primitive = this;`
and 
`in->differentialGeometry = differentialGeometry;` of `Primitive.h`. Why is this?

Am I forward declaring and using my `include` statements (for `Primitive` and `Intersection`) in the usual, correct way?

Comment: You cannot do any operations or dereferencing on just forward declared types.

Comment: "intersection.h" and "Intersection.h" are not necessarily the same file...

Comment: Declare differentialGeometry correctly - you typed differntialGeometry,

Comment: Things like `in->primitive = this;` require that the compiler know what the structure of `in` is, and a forward declaration doesn't provide that.

Comment: And you don't have a member named differentialGeometry in Intersection

Answer (score 1):

You cannot actually use forward declared types. Forward declaration only tells the compiler that there is a type with that name, but not its size or its members. As a result you cannot instantiate it or call any of its member functions. What you can do is declare pointers or references to it (usually function parameters), as all pointers have the same size.

Forward declared functions are different, as you tell the compiler not ony their name, nut also their signature, wich is enough for the compiler to create the call side code (e.g. preparing parameters, allocating space for return value and jump to a symbol, which the linker will later translate into an actual address

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just forgot to put

```
#ifndef Intersection_H
#define Intersection_H
```

Without this condition you are including intersection.h 2 times and resulting in an error.
Take a look at this article:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard

Comment: Those include guards are invalid, as they use multiple, consecutive underscores.

Comment: I'll use it in my program! Can you provide a link that show me why they are invalid?

Comment: You gave that link yourself.

Comment: My apologies; I actually do have the include guards in both the `Primitive.h` file and the `Intersection.h` file; I've updated the original post to reflect this. I'm still confused though -- why do I need `#include "intersection.h" in `Primitive.h`?

Comment: See retired ninja's comment.